# Can Adobe .jsx scripts include other script files?

Tags: scripting, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

We're writing a bunch of .jsx scripts and in each I have to mock out some functions so I can use things like Array.map() and String.trim(), but I don't want to have to include that code at the top of every script.

Is there a way to "include" other .jsx scripts inside of a .jsx script file?

Comment: I realized this is better suited for Graphic Design's stack exchange here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17007/can-adobe-illustrator-jsx-scripts-include-other-script-files/17014

Answer (score 18):

Or you can simply use `#include` and `#includepath` preprocessor directives at the top of your script.
You can find a detailed description in [Adobe's "JavaScript Tools Guide"](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html).

For example, if you want to include `scripts/helper.jsx` in a `.jsx` file:

```
#include "scripts/helpers.jsx"
// the rest of your code below ...
```

Comment: Been trying forever! Thanks :)

Comment: I tried to inject jsx files contents from Premiere to AfterEffects via BridgeTalk.
This works, but if I try to send the JSON library this way, it doesn't work.
The solution was to only send `#include "' + pathToScriptFile + '";` instead of the script contents.

Answer (score 3):

Just leaving this here for anyone like me who is looking for this. In Adobe Illustrator CC 2015, I was unable to get `#include` to work, but `@include` did. So for example:

## External File: foo.jsx

```
function alertTheWordNo(){
  alert('NO');
}
```

## The Script File: bar.jsx

```
//@include 'foo.jsx';
alertTheWordNo();
```

Disclaimer: I cannot find any documentation of this but have tested it with Adobe Illustrator CC 2015 and it works.

Hope this helps someone. If anyone has any questions just ask!

Comment: Adobe CC 2017 (v21.0.0) both #include and //@include work for me. At https://forums.adobe.com/thread/290259, I see "//@ is needed for backwards compatibility with CS and maybe CS2. This is documented in the JS Tools Guide in the ESTK chapter." So I guess that #include is preferable.

Comment: This will work, but you MUST add a CEFCommandLine argument to your manifest.xml allowing file access, or the primary JSX will seemingly not load or evaluate the external file!

Answer (score 0):

We're now using the `$` helper available in Illustrator, and the `$.evalFile()` method. Pass it a path and it will evaluate the file and return the result.

I created a little helper that I can include (minified, of course) at the top of my .jsx scripts so I can do `Libraries.include("my-other-script")` that will include, in my case, a file that's in my `adobe_scripts` root folder, in a directory called `lib`.

```
// indexOf polyfill from https://gist.github.com/atk/1034425
[].indexOf||(Array.prototype.indexOf=function(a,b,c){for(c=this.length,b=(c+~~b)%c;b<c&&(!(b in this)||this[b]!==a);b++);return b^c?b:-1;});

var Libraries = (function (libPath) {    
    return {
        include: function (path) {
            if (!path.match(/\.jsx$/i)) { 
                path = path + ".jsx"; 
            }
            return $.evalFile(libPath + path);
        }
    };
})($.fileName.split("/").splice(0, $.fileName.split("/").indexOf("adobe_scripts") + 1).join("/") + "/lib/");
```

Minified version that I include:

```
/**
 * Libraries.include(path) -- path must be relative to adobe_scripts/lib/
 * See: https://gist.github.com/jasonrhodes/5286526
 */
[].indexOf||(Array.prototype.indexOf=function(a,b,c){for(c=this.length,b=(c+~~b)%c;b<c&&(!(b in this)||this[b]!==a);b++);return b^c?b:-1;});var Libraries=function(a){return{include:function(b){return b.match(/\.jsx$/i)||(b+=".jsx"),$.evalFile(a+b)}}}($.fileName.split("/").splice(0,$.fileName.split("/").indexOf("adobe_scripts")+1).join("/")+"/lib/");
```

See gist here: https://gist.github.com/jasonrhodes/5286526

Comment: A better way is to use [require](https://github.com/theiviaxx/PSLib/blob/master/require.jsx) from [CommonJS for Photoshop](https://github.com/theiviaxx/PSLib). I think that works for all the apps on the suite. To include require.jsx just use "#include require.jsx".

Comment: How would I include a js file in jsx using require? @jkutianski

Comment: Just use
`var _ = require('underscore');`
Look at this source https://github.com/theiviaxx/PSLib/blob/master/lib/template.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a note to Ike10's answer. Undocumented is generous - this is the worst "documentation" I've ever come across in 20+ years of writing code. It seems to me that you must also add the CEFCommandLine argument to your manifest.xml file before the primary JSX file will load/eval external files:

```
<Resources>
    <MainPath>./whatever.html</MainPath>
    <ScriptPath>./jsx/whatever.jsx</ScriptPath>
    <CEFCommandLine>
        <Parameter>--allow-file-access</Parameter>
        <Parameter>--allow-file-access-from-files</Parameter>
    </CEFCommandLine>
</Resources>
```