# How do I reference another JS file for Illustrator Scripts?

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I have illustrator scripts that select Layers and other scripts that move items to named layers.

I want to create one file where I can name all the layers as variables, I have some experience with PHP and I understand the include function. I need something similar that will work with JS.

I have tried the code from this link - [jQuery.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

But I am getting errors, so it seems I am missing something (I don't have any experience with JS). I'm not even sure if Illustrator works like that.

This is the code

```
var aDoc = app.activeDocument;

$.getScript( "LayerNames.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});

aDoc.activeLayer = aDoc.layers.getByName(layerName1);
```

LayerNames.js has the following code

```
var layerName1 = 'Background';
```

The error I get is `$.getScript` is not a function.

So, the question is, can I reference an external js file in an illustrator script and if yes, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Adobe .jsx scripts include other script files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746335/can-adobe-jsx-scripts-include-other-script-files)

Comment: This didn't show up in any searches I did, but its basicallty the same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to be

```
#include "sample.jsx"
```

This works perfectly for my case senario.